# Code suggestion in src/test is not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 0.3.5, and I am having an issue where code suggestion in `src/test` directly is not working.

Whenever I type classes of Robolectric, mockito, or JUnit in any of the files in `src/test`, it does not give me a code suggestion like it does in `src/main` directory.
In `src/main`, when I type a name of class that is not included in `import`, it not only gives me code suggestion, but it also auto add the selected class in `import` if missing.

Is there any way I can enable the functionality in `src/test`?

I am using Android Studio 0.3.5 and here is the my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
}

sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/test/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/resources')
    }
}

configurations {
    unitTestCompile.extendsFrom runtime
    unitTestRuntime.extendsFrom unitTestCompile
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.2.1'

    unitTestCompile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
    unitTestCompile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'
    unitTestCompile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
    unitTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.0'
    unitTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    unitTestCompile 'com.google.android:android:4.0.1.2'
    unitTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.2'
    unitTestCompile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.2.2'
    unitTestCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.2.1'

    unitTestCompile files("$project.buildDir/classes/release")

}

task unitTest(type:Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
    description = "run unit tests"
    testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = project.sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
}

check.dependsOn unitTest
```

and here is the structure of the project

```
.
├── example.iml
├── build.gradle
├── local.properties
├── src
│   ├── instrumentTest
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── com
│   │           └──example
│   │               └──demo
│   │                   └── test
│   │                       └── MainActivityTest.java
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └──example
│   │   │           └──demo
│   │   │           ... 
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       │   └── com
│       │       └──example
│       │           └──demo
│       │               ├── ui
│       │               │   ├── PreferencesActivityTest.java
│       │               │...
```

Comment: I get stuck into the same situation this moment. Have you found any available solution now?